# Tengo problemas para guardar una cookie en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Mi problema es que intento crear una cookie para saber cual es el usuario que esta utilizando la web, el sistema que quiero intentar es bastante sencillo, simplemente quiero crear la cookie a partir del correo de la persona que quiera iniciar sesion, la cookie deberia crearse aunque el correo sea incorrecto -Esto da igual ya que la web no tiene información sensible y el formulario de login no dejará entrar al usuario si proporciona los datos incorrectos -.

Pero resulta que por algún motivo javascript no agrega la cookie , ¿me podéis ayudar?

```
<script>

  var identiu = function(){     
        document.cookie = "identi=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/127.0.0.1";
        var name = identi;
        var value = document.getElementById("emailusuario");
       document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";path=/127.0.0.1";
   }
    </script>
```

Comment: Directamente las cookie no las he manejado; prefiero y he usado (en web) el manejo de sesiones conforme al leguaje en uso (PHP y .NET lo que uso) que igualmente poseen turinas para el manejo de cookies; te sugiero no lo hagas en el cliente sino desde el servidor. Suerte espero te sirva de orientación.

Comment: Lo que estás tratando hacer se llama **sesión** y debe de hacerse en lo más posible en el backend o si se hace en el cliente, usar un token. Usar cookies ahora ya no tiene suficientes ventajas para las sesiones.

Comment: Bienvenido HatCliff. Es conveniente que sigas el [tour] y que leas [ask] para conocer algunos de los elementos básicos del funcionamiento de este sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta de esta manera:

```
<script>

  var identiu = function(){     
        document.cookie = "identi=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
        var name = identi;
        var value = document.getElementById("emailusuario");
       document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/";
   }
</script>
```

Ademas como te dicen nunca trates de crear las cookies desde el cliente, trata de hacerlo desde el mismo PHP.

Comment: El autor de la pregunta no menciona que esté usando PHP.

Comment: No digo que el usa PHP, solo menciono en mi respuesta que seria preferible que la maneje desde PHP. Ademas mi trate de darle una solucion basa en JavaScript y no desde PHP